# Is it possible to upload archive in aws-glacier with sync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, synchronization, archive, amazon-glacier

I using upload-archive tool to upload folder on aws Glacier. but the problem i set a cron to upload-archive every 1 month with sync. so is it possible to upload archives with synchronization ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the `aws glacier upload-archive` command within the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

The CLI **does not** support a `sync` command for use with Glacier.

You must determine the archives (files) you wish to upload and specify them as part of the command.

Alternatively, you could use `aws s3 sync` to send the files to Amazon S3 and then use a [lifecycle policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to move the files to Glacier after a given period of time.